# Deploying ARM with Azure DevOps: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to deploy ARM with Azure DevOps.
path to Git repo is "ARMTemplates\CreateSQLServerARM\azuredeploy.json"
However I'm getting error. What could be wrong?

ERROR:

```
 Checking if the following resource group exists: KensTestRG.
 Resource group exists: true.
 Creating deployment parameters.
 ##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern
 Finishing: AzureResourceGroupDeployment
```

Code:
    # Starter pipeline

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
-     task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    ConnectedServiceName: 'AzureRmPipeline-conn'
    subscriptionId: '1111753a-501e-4e46-9aff-6120ed562222'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'KensTestRG'
    location: 'North Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'ARMTemplates\CreateSQLServerARM\azuredeploy.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
```

- script: |
  echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
  echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates the azuredeploy.json file specified in parameter csmFile cannot be found.

When azure agent builds your pipeline, the repo source code is cloned in the default working folder (`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` ie. `c:\agent_work\1\s`) on the agent machine.  If your repo is like below:

[image]

Then the folder structure is like below in the agent machine.

```
s |
   - Deploymentfiles
     |
     - StorageAccount 
       |
       - **.json
   - VirtualNetwork
     |
      ...
   - readme.md
```

And the path for csmFile should be `csmFile: 'Deploymentfiles\StorageAccount\azuredeploy.json'`

However you can also use wildcard like below example, if you are not sure about the folders structure.

`csmFile: '**\azuredeploy.json'`

`csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\azuredeploy.json'`

**Update**:

If the pipeline targets ubuntu agents. "/" should be used in the file path for `csmFile` field. ("\" is for the file path in windows system).

`csmFile: 'ARMTemplates/CreateSQLServerARM/azuredeploy.json'`

`csmFile: '**/azuredeploy.json'`

`csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/azuredeploy.json'`

Comment: These did not work for me: csmFile: '**\azuredeploy.json'

csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\azuredeploy.json'    csmFile: '\ARMTemplates\CreateSQLServerARM\azuredeploy.json'

Comment: Hi @Kenny_I I just noticed you were using agent `ubuntu-latest`, Please replace the '\' in the file's path to '/' for linux system. Check out above update.

Comment: replace the '\' in the file and it works fine now. Thanks!